# getting records of second entity through join

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the below two pojos which have one to many relationships my query is that right now through SqlResultSetMapping I am able to fetch the results of first class that is Com but inside Com there is reference of SubCom also but as the result of my current SqlResultSetMapping the output that I am getting is perfect but it contains null for SubCom so please advise how can I modify my SqlResultSetMapping  that I will get the value of SubCom also, shall I design separate SqlResultSetMapping for SubCom.

First Pojo is shown below

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "firstQuery",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = com.entity.Com.class,
                columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "com_Id" , type = Integer.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "Cescription" , type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "name" , type = String.class)}))




@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "COM")
public class Com implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

        @Column(name = "com_Id")
        private Integer ComId;

          private String Cescription;
        private String name;




    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Com", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<SubCom> subCom = new ArrayList<>(); // *** Has a refrence


    //**** Constructor  

       public Com( Integer ComId , String Cescription,  String name) {
        this.ComId=ComId;
        this.Cescription = Cescription;
        this.name = name;

    }


}
```

My second pojo is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sub_com")
@Data
public class SubCom implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "sub_com_id")
  private Integer Id;

  private String name;
  private String Cescription;


  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
  @JoinColumn(name = "com_Id")
  private Com com; //****** Refernce to above table.

  }
```

I have executed the native sql query which looks like below

```
SELECT
    c.com_Id,
    c.Cescription,
    sc.sub_domain_id
    FROM Com AS c
         INNER JOIN SubCom AS sc ON c.com_Id  = sc.com_Id
```

Comment: How  does your SQL look like?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have updated the same please

Comment: That are not all fields that are required to construct both entities. You should add all columns from both entities

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sorry you mean to say in the recent sql native query

Answer (score 0):

You have to select all necessary columns to construct the both entities.

Than the mapping will look like in this example:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "find_person_with_phones_by_name",
    query =
        "SELECT " +
        "   pr.id AS \"pr.id\", " +
        "   pr.name AS \"pr.name\", " +
        "   pr.nickName AS \"pr.nickName\", " +
        "   pr.address AS \"pr.address\", " +
        "   pr.createdOn AS \"pr.createdOn\", " +
        "   pr.version AS \"pr.version\", " +
        "   ph.id AS \"ph.id\", " +
        "   ph.person_id AS \"ph.person_id\", " +
        "   ph.phone_number AS \"ph.number\", " +
        "   ph.phone_type AS \"ph.type\" " +
        "FROM Person pr " +
        "JOIN Phone ph ON pr.id = ph.person_id " +
        "WHERE pr.name LIKE :name",
    resultSetMapping = "person_with_phones"
)
 @SqlResultSetMapping(
     name = "person_with_phones",
     entities = {
         @EntityResult(
             entityClass = Person.class,
             fields = {
                 @FieldResult( name = "id", column = "pr.id" ),
                 @FieldResult( name = "name", column = "pr.name" ),
                 @FieldResult( name = "nickName", column = "pr.nickName" ),
                 @FieldResult( name = "address", column = "pr.address" ),
                 @FieldResult( name = "createdOn", column = "pr.createdOn" ),
                 @FieldResult( name = "version", column = "pr.version" ),
             }
         ),
         @EntityResult(
             entityClass = Phone.class,
             fields = {
                 @FieldResult( name = "id", column = "ph.id" ),
                 @FieldResult( name = "person", column = "ph.person_id" ),
                 @FieldResult( name = "number", column = "ph.number" ),
                 @FieldResult( name = "type", column = "ph.type" ),
             }
         )
     }
 ),
```

Please find more information in the Hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html